# How to check which certificate is being checked for revocation?

Tags: windows, certificate-revocation

I have a .net desktop application **without a certificate** on a network not connected to the Internet

When I start it, there is a call to crl.microsoft.com that times out and slows down the application.

I know I can put

```
<runtime>
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false" />
</runtime>
```

to skip the check, but I'm curious to know **what triggers** this check and **which certificate** does it want to check? Is there a way to "sniff" that information?

Comment: I'm sure there is a trace provider that will allow you to "sniff" that.  Possibly under the WIF or IIS types?

Answer (score 1):

[This MSDN blog may help you](https://web.archive.org/web/20160210015323/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/kaushal/archive/2012/10/15/disable-client-certificate-revocation-check-on-iis.aspx)

One way of doing this is listed below, but others are on the blog

```
REGISTRY  : HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo 
DWORD    : DefaultSslCertCheckMode 
Value         : 1
```

Comment: my .net application is a desktop one, this msdn link talk about IIS, i'm going to try it but i'm sure it wont work